# XGBoostClassifier object creation is giving JavaPacksge error

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, xgboost

Using `sparkxgb` library for simple classification but it's failing with JavaPackage error (using colab notebook).

```
from sparkxgb.xgboost import XGBoostClassificationModel, XGBoostClassifier 

xgb = XGBoostClassifier(objective="binary:logistic",seed=1712,
                        featuresCol="features",
                        labelCol="label",
                        missing=0.0,
                        )
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-de59aac4b383> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 xgb = XGBoostClassifier(objective="binary:logistic",
      2                         featuresCol="features",
      3                         labelCol="label",
      4                         missing=0.0,
      5                         )

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _new_java_obj(java_class, *args)
     64             java_obj = getattr(java_obj, name)
     65         java_args = [_py2java(sc, arg) for arg in args]
---> 66         return java_obj(*java_args)
     67 
     68     @staticmethod

TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```